# Variables in Redis configuration file

Tags: redis

I would like to set a `REDIS_ROOT` in my `redis.conf` file and be able to reuse that same variable across a number of other configuration points. I want to have all my logs, dumps, etc. go somewhere in this directory... something like `$REDIS_ROOT/logs/redis.log`.

Is there a way to set a variable of this kind in the Redis configuration file? Or am I stuck retyping it over and over (or doing some find-replace wizardry before using the `conf` file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There does not appear to be any way to do this with Redis config files. However, there are only a couple places you should need to use a directory, unless you are doing a lot of includes. Redis configuration just isn't very complicated.

Comment: Thanks, you confirm my suspicion.